# Installing Design tool on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, justinmind

I want to install Justinmind prototype design tool in my laptop. Unfortunately the software is not available for ubuntu but only for windows and mac... Is there any other way to install it. tell me.

Comment: You can install `wine`. There is a thread about it here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/657586/how-to-install-justinmind-prototyper-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Currently Justinmind design tool is not available to ubuntu.
So you can try with Wine.